# How to get list Level in Word(with Pandoc+Markdown)

Tags: ms-word, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying **Pandoc** with Markdown to Make various Documents.
I built a Word(.docx) Document from a Markdown document but that document get no nest at lists, example below images.

[Exsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BOSK.png)

Markdown document source is here.

```
* contentA
    + contentA-1
    + contentA-2
        - contentA-2-1
```

As you can See, Left tab is OK, but indent is not working.
I want to get lists with indent.
Please Tell me how to get indented list on Pandoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice in your screenshot, the lines in your list are separated with a line break rather than a new paragraph. So that's why there is no nesting on subsequent lines; each is considered a continuation of the first list item.

Try using the ["loose" list format in pandoc's markdown](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#lists). That should format each line of your list as a separate paragraph, which should make them nest properly.

Later, that same evening...

Hmm. Perhaps I was wrong. I just copy/pasted your markdown into a new file and converted it to docx and it nested just fine for me.

[image: nested list works]

This was just using a simple:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t docx -o test_nested_lists.docx test_nested_lists.md
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.
As a Result, My own Word Template is Just wrong.
I edited default template: "reference.docx", that makes my lists broken.
May be editing '標準' style causes this problem.(I'm Japanese and I don't know the English Name of that Style, sorry)

I'm sorry that My stupid Question, But Your Suggest that "just copy/paste brought the fine lists" is very helpful for me,
because that reminds me that Pandoc command and Markdown Source is OK,
So I checked my Template and finally find what is wrong.

Thank you for your answer, and taking time.